# Can you pass a variable by reference to a callback method in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, callback, tkinter, event-handling

I'm working on a GUI using `tkinter` in Python 3, and I have an `Entry` text box named `inputFilePathDisplay` with the following binding:

```
inputFilePathDisplay.bind("<Key>", lambda event, filePath = inputFilePath: key(event, filePath))
```

I have the following callback function for when a key is pressed:

```
#input functions -- see if the user has entered text
def key(event, filePath):
    filePath = event.widget.get()
```

My goal is to get the input in the `Entry` box and assign it to `inputFilePath`. I can see that the `filePath` variable is changed in the `key()` function, but the value for `inputFilePath` is not updated. I'm fairly new to Python, so I'm not as familiar with how it handles passing arguments by reference. What is it I'm missing?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Python passes arguments by value. However **all** values in python are just references to objects. You could say what happens is that it's a pass by *copy* of reference. Hopefully, if you think some time about this, you'll understand better what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
filePath = event.widget.get()
```

You are changing the value of the local variable `filepath` from the value passed into the function, to the value returned by `event.widget.get()`. The value passed into the function is lost at this point.

You can't assign to a caller's variable passed in in this manner. For one thing, what if they didn't pass in a variable?

Common practice in most situations is simply to return the value. If this isn't possible, as it isn't in this case, you can have your function take a mutable container, such as a list, dictionary, or class instance, and modify that. `tkinter` provides just such mutable classes for various basic types, such as `StringVar`.

So, you define a `StringVar` instance, you set its value using the `set()` method, and you can then retrieve it later using `get()`.

So your `key` function looks like this:

```
def key(event, filePath):
    filePath.set(event.widget.get())
```

And your binding looks like this:

```
inputFilePath = StringVar()
inputFilePathDisplay.bind("<Key>", lambda event, filePath=inputFilePath: key(event, filePath))
```

Another possibility (which from a quick Googling I see is preferred by many `tkinter` programmers) is to make your callback function a bound method on some class instance. Then you can store the value as an attribute on the instance. This has the advantage that the method already knows what object it's connected to (through `self`), so you don't need to deal with that explicitly. Since you only need the one method, let's make the instance callable!

```
class StrHolder(object):
    def __call__(self, event):
        self.value = event.widget.get()
```

Now your binding can be, e.g.:

```
inputFilePath = StrHolder()
inputFilePathDisplay.bind("<Key>", inputFilePath)
```

And to retrieve the value later, reference `inputFilePath.value`. You could even embellish the `StrHolder` class so it works more or less like a string without having to reference the attribute.

Comment: It's not a common practice to return something in a binding. The caller of a binding (the event loop) throws away the return value of bound functions.

Comment: How, then, can I ensure that the new data in the `Entry` field will be assigned to the `inputFilePath` variable?

Comment: Updated this, hope it helps.